# How can I request that my FOIA request to the US CBP is not made publicly available?

Tags: united-states, privacy

Freedom of Information Act (FOIA) requests to the U.S. Customs and Border Protection
(US CBP) are made publicly available, [e.g.](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2022-Jun/6%20-%20FOIA%20Log%20June%202019.pdf):

[image]

Sometime the information is redacted, sometime it isn't.

How can I request my FOIA request to the US CBP not to be made publicly available? (= redact name + description)

If that matters, I'm a French citizen (maybe the General Data Protection Regulation applies?).

Comment: I'd better ask it on Law.SE, since the main point of that question is inclined to Exception 6 (*(b)(6)*) and it is extremely vague as usual (see [foia wiki](https://foia.wiki/wiki/Exemption_6)), GDPR doesn't apply to EU citizens outside of the EU anyways

Comment: An even more basic question is, how to you make a FOIA request at all, now that they don't participate in FOIAonline.

Comment: @user6726 they = CBP?

Comment: Yes, CBP is them

Comment: The GDPR isn’t going to apply — the EU can regulate businesses operating in the EU, but it has no authority to regulate a foreign sovereign. That’s why cases about US surveillance laws have been “can businesses transfer data from the EU to the US” and not “I accuse the US of violating the GDPR.”

Comment: @user6726 Now the whole DHS switched to [SecureRelease](https://www.securerelease.us/account-page/sign-in/)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Are they even still publicising the actual content of the request? Latest [logs](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2022-Oct/FOIA%20Log%20-%20September%202022.pdf) only mention 1st/3rd party request and the name of the requester

Comment: @NicolasFormichella thanks, good catch, no idea